# Force Video to play in Portrait Orientation only using MediaPlayer and VideoView

Tags: android, video, orientation, media-player, android-videoview

I am writing an activity that will play a video file on my SD card. I have this code working.

The orientation of the video is based on if my phone is vertical or horizontal. I want to force my video to play horizontally (like the default player). Is there a way to do this?

My code:

Layout

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

  <VideoView android:id="@+id/VideoView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </VideoView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Video Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   this.setContentView(R.layout.video_view);
   mVideoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
   String videoUrl = "/mnt/sdcard-ext" + "/Videos/Wildlife.wmv";
   MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
   mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
   mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
   mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
   mVideoView.requestFocus(); 
   mVideoView.start();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just thought off trying to locking the orientation...
I'll give that a try and post back.

Comment: Yup, that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: can you please post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I'll answer this question. This has been posted several times before. Go to your Android Manifest and add this to the activity declaration that you want to lock the orientation

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: The view is still landscape.